# Changing color of a beamer presentation (Szeged-dove)

Tags: beamer, color, themes

I am working on beamer presentation, *Szeged* theme and *dove* colortheme.
Basically, I'd like to change the color of all the dove-colored lines and the text that's between them to a  RGB value set with `\definecolor` without changing anything else.

Thanks very much in advance for any help!

Comment: Can you maybe ask a separate question about your font problem and include a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) of what does not work? It is very hard to diagnose why a code is not working when we don't see the code.

Comment: I'll try and edit this one to make it clearer but if I don't succed I'll surely write a new one!

Comment: Please ask for the font problem in a separate question. It is better for the site if a question does not mix different problems. Imagine if some future user also wants to change the colour. Then we can direct him to this question. But if your question contains a mixture if things, it will be more difficult for future users to find a solution.

Comment: I see, I'll do it now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The colour of the lines is controlled by `separation line` colour. You can change this colour to whatever colour you have defined:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\definecolor{mycolor}{RGB}{255,0,0}

\usetheme{Szeged}
\usecolortheme{dove}

\setbeamercolor{separation line}{bg=mycolor}

\setbeamercolor{title in head/foot}{fg=mycolor}
\setbeamercolor{institute in head/foot}{fg=mycolor}
\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{fg=mycolor}

\title{text}
\author{names}
\institute{institute}

\begin{document}

\section{title}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{title}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much! Is there a way so that the text that appears between separation lines (chapter names and dots on the header; title of the presentation and author name on the footer) is of the same color "mycolor" instead of black?

Comment: @luciadefinetti Sure, you can do things like `\setbeamercolor{title in head/foot}{fg=mycolor}`. Can you make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that contains all elements for which you want to change the colour?

Comment: @luciadefinetti Please see my edited answer. I guessed a few more elements which might be between the lines.

Comment: Thank you very much: you guessed well indeed :)

Comment: @luciadefinetti Good to hear!

Comment: Hmmh, you *really* do not have my crystal ball? The above communication is very suspicious. ;-)

Comment: @marmot :) Crystal ball factory: `\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikzlings}
\begin{document}
\foreach \x in {1,...,100}{\tikz{\tikzling[crystalball];}}
\end{document}`

Comment: Is the tikzlings package online? (see how much I'd need a crystal ball ;-)

Comment: @marmot it is not yet on ctan, but I will submit it soon. At the moment it is only available from https://github.com/samcarter/tikzlings

Comment: @samcarter any way to set to "mycolor" not only the text between first and second separation line but also the one between second and third (that is, the current subsection name)? Thanks very much in advance :)

Comment: @luciadefinetti Try `subsection in head/foot`

Comment: @samcarter perfect, thank you very much again :)